# Please Check the Update Query is not working. I am new to Mysql please

Tags: php, mysql

the code is as under.....The  Error is Invalid Query. and it is not Updating the table in database. Anyone help please..

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$selecteditem=$_POST['salesitem'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$purchasePrice=$_POST['purchase'];
$salePrice=$_POST['sale'];
$iteminPack=$_POST['nofiteminpack'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$GenName=$_POST['genric'];
$norcotics=$_POST['radio1'];
$stockinHand=$_POST['stockInHand'];
$conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("alkausar",$conn);
$qr2="UPDATE `item` SET name=$name,type=$type,pPrice=$purchasePrice,sPrice=$salePrice,Iteminpack=$iteminPack,location=$location,genricName=$GenName,norcotics=$norcotics,stockInHand=$stockinHand WHERE name='$selecteditem'";
$qr3=mysql_query($qr2);
echo $qr3;
if(!$qr3){
            die('Invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
            }
?>
```

Comment: String values needs to be in quotes `name='$name',type='$type'....` better use Prepared Statement.

Comment: you need to do like this `name='$name'`. you missed single quotes.Please update and try.

Comment: Please, stop using mysql functions, it is deprecated and will not work in the future. Use PDO or mysqli instead, and check at prepared statement.

Comment: print the query on front and execute on back end directly..you will come to know more by prcatical

Answer (score 0):

You should put all inputs in `'`

```
$qr2="UPDATE `item` SET
name='$name',
type='$type',
Price='$purchasePrice',
sPrice='$salePrice',
Iteminpack='$iteminPack',
location='$location',
genricName='$GenName',
norcotics='$norcotics',
stockInHand='$stockinHand'
WHERE name='$selecteditem'";
```

Depending on what you have in `$_POST` this could already solve your problem.

If not, echo `$qr2` and try to run in the the DB manually and see if you get an error message.